# Why in Python I can't concatenate string and number like in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python

The programming language Python is very concise . In comparison with the JavaScript you do not need a lot of parentheses, semicolons and `var`. One thing has always seemed to me at odds with this philosophy is the fact of not being able to concatenate strings and numbers. Without  previously converting the number to strings with `str ()` or with other constructs such as `% s% s% (Variale, variable)`. Which are the theoretical reasons of this choice?

```
JavaScript:
console.log("I can c"+0+"ncat"+3+"nate a "+1+"ot of num"+63+"rs!")

Python:
print "I can c%incat%inate a %iot of num%irs!" %(0,3,1,63)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
i can c0ncat3nate a 1ot of num63rs!
```

### Edit: the answer suggested by Ashwini

I don't know why this question has been closed however  Ashwini Chaudhary post the link where you can find the answer. **So is not an opinion** but a fact based on theoretical issues. Here is the extract from the [documentation page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Why%20is%20Python%20a%20dynamic%20language%20and%20also%20a%20strongly%20typed%20language):

> In a strongly typed language, you are simply not allowed to do
>   anything that's incompatible with the type of data you're working
>   with. For example, in a weakly typed language you can typically do 3 +
>   5 + 7 and get the result 15, because numbers can be added; similarly,
>   you can often do 'Hello' + 'And' + 'Goodbye' and get the result
>   "HelloAndGoodBye", because strings support concatenation. But in a
>   strongly-typed language you can't do 'Hello' + 5 + 'Goodbye', because
>   there's no defined way to "add" strings and numbers to each other. In
>   a weakly typed language, the compiler or interpreter can perform
>   behind-the-scenes conversions to make these types of operations work;
>   for example, a weakly typed language might give you the string
>   "Hello5Goodbye" as a result for 'Hello' + 5 + 'Goodbye'. The advantage
>   to a strongly typed language is that you can trust what's going on: if
>   you do something wrong, your program will generate a type error
>   telling you where you went wrong, and you don't have to memorize a lot
>   of arcane type-conversion rules or try to debug a situation where your
>   variables have been silently changed without your knowledge

.

Comment: [Why is Python a dynamic language and also a strongly typed language](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Why%20is%20Python%20a%20dynamic%20language%20and%20also%20a%20strongly%20typed%20language)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary astonishing speed! straight to the answer I was looking for! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Adriano is not opinon-based! as Ashwine shows me there is the answer in python documentation:

Comment: [answer](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Why%20is%20Python%20a%20dynamic%20language%20and%20also%20a%20strongly%20typed%20language)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because implicit conversion is a major source of bugs

a more readable alternative in python 2.6 and upwards would be

```
 print ("I can c{}ncat{}nate a {}ot of num{}rs!".format(0,3,1,63))
```